# Twitter gem usage - Faraday builder error

Tags: ruby, twitter-gem

I’m trying to use twitter gem and getting

```
Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder
```

when I run the code. Anybody else got this or have idea how to resolve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this error by upgrading `twitter` gem to current stable. Seems like you use old version and it calls `Faraday::Builder` instead of `Faraday::RackBuilder`, [which triggers this warning](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday.rb#L233).

So there are 2 possible solutions:

1. To upgrade `twitter gem` version to stable, which uses `Faraday::RackBuilder`
2. To downgrade `faraday gem` version, where you suppose to use `Faraday::Builder`(0.8.x if I remember correctly)